# Bar Chart show customized max 3 labels chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using bar chart from chart.js library, I want the bar labels to be maximum 3 (like in image) with customized label.

I used `maxTicksLimit: 3` which works but not as expected, the maxTicksLimit shows random three labels but I want with custom value and at start center and end like in image.

```
    labels: ['January 2023', 'February 2023', 'March 2023', 'April 2023', 'May 2023', 'June 2023', 'July 2023'],
     scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: true,
          maxTicksLimit: 3
        }
      },
   }
```

[image]